# Cloud Speech-to-Text bad sample rate hertz

Tags: json, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Attempting to emulate audio to text through Cloud Shell as outlined in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-speech-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0-

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "languageCode": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}
```

This works.
Using same config, and loading the brooklyn.flac file obtained from the above codelabs document (file is actually a .wav) into a bucket and calling that address in the "audio" string, returns following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid recognition 'config': bad sample rate hertz.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Same error occurs with other files encoded per requirements outlined in https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding (16 bit, 16KHz, mono, WAV, FLAC encoding)
In addition, use of "sampleRateHertz" and "ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED" per the above AudioEncoding ref also return invalid argument errors.
Have searched the boards with keywords "config': bad sample rate hertz." with no luck.
What is strange is that the FLAC file called in the codelabs doc is a .wav when downloaded and doesn't work when moved to my bucket.
Any ideas welcome- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The codelabs document is a bit confusing, they actually transcribe the FLAC file under following address gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac (download the flac file at https://storage.cloud.google.com/speech-demo/brooklyn.flac) but for preview they suggest different file with WAV under address https://storage.cloud.google.com/speech-demo/brooklyn.wav. This is because not many browsers can play flac but most can play wav. The WAV file is only for preview, not for transcription.

If you put WAV file into bucket, you need to adjust parameters according to WAV format. Or you still can download FLAC file and use it as the recommend.